# Angular Google Auth2

Tags: angular, google-oauth

Sorry for stupid question, but i'm new in Angular 
When I'm logging in: button changes from login to logout, but then I'm refreshing page all turns back

this is my template:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-8 top-panel-right">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right panel-menu">
  <li *ngIf="(isSignedIn | async) == false">
     <button class="btn-link" (click)="googleAuthObject.signIn()">
        Login
     </button>
  </li>
  <li  *ngIf="isSignedIn| async">
    <button class="btn-link" (click)="googleAuthObject.signOut()">
       Logout
    </button>
  </li>
```

this is my component:

```
public googleAuthObject;

public isSignedIn: Observable<boolean>;

constructor (private googleAuth: GoogleOauth) {
    let that = this;
    this.googleAuth.getOauth((googleAuth)  => {
        that.googleAuthObject = googleAuth;
        googleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(that.signInCheking);
        that.signInCheking(googleAuth.isSignedIn.get());
    });
}

public signInCheking(isSignedIn: boolean) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
        console.log(isSignedIn);
        this.isSignedIn = Observable.of(isSignedIn);
    }
}
```

googleAuth.isSignedIn.get();

returns true, but isSignedIn and templates doesn't updates

this is my google-client-wrapper:

```
private scope = [
    'profile',
].join(' ');

public getOauth(callback){
    let that = this;
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: that.clientId,
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            scope: that.scope
        }).then(callback)

    });
}
```

Comment: Note: Don't think your question is stupid or something negative, even simple questions can have the value in here.